# How to find min in time and max out time from table using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have a MySQL Table. I need to find MIN IN TIME AND MAX OUT TIME using MySQL.

[image]

Comment: show the code you have tried

Comment: share the query which you have tried

Comment: will be if u use only one column for IN and OUT each and use 24Hours instead 12Hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unique column for the H24 time it would be better..but do the actual column you could use

```
select min( case when in_am is null then in_pm else in_am end) as min_in,
       max( case when out_pm is null then out_am else iout_pm end) as max_out
from my_table;
```